# webpackのパッケージ依存について

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

こんにちは、初めまして。

今Reactで開発を始めようと環境を作っているところですが、
npmでwebpackをインストールするところでバージョン依存ではまっています。

最新の webpac@k4.8.3 を使いたいのですが、
インストールしようとすると以下が出ます。
webpack4.8.3 => UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY ajv@6.5.0

上記が出たので、
ajv@6.5.0 をインストールしよう、とすると以下が出ます。
ajv6.5.0 => UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@3.8.1

＃循環になっているように見受けられます。
　仕方ないので、webpack@3.8.1 を入れて進めました。

browser-sync や react-hot-loader など、
周辺のライブラリを入れようとすると上記のような依存エラーが
出ることが良くありますが、
皆さん開発の時にはどのようにしているのでしょうか。
＃バージョンを決めてしまって、一気に入れれば上記のようなことは
　起こらないかもしれませんが、それだと今の開発には合わないように思います。

Answer (score 1):

webpackの最新バージョンを使う際、
各ライブラリが、webpackの最新バージョンに対応していない場合があるので
対応するまではwebpackのバージョンを落として対応するなどする必要があるかと思います。

またnodeのバージョンを合わせていないと起こる場合もあるため、気をつける必要があります。

各ライブラリは、都度バージョンアップしているため、
webpack最新バージョンに対応ができしだい、都度合わせる必要があるかと思います。

ただ、webpackなどは日々バージョンアップしているため
個人的にはプロジェクトを始めるときに安定しているバージョンで作り始めるのがよいかなと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！やはりwebpack側を下げて進める必要があるのですね。周辺の各ライブラリも日々かなりの勢いでバージョンアップしているので、Reactでチーム開発する場合は、やはり都度パッケージバージョンの統制を取るメンテナーが１人は必ず必要ですね。ありがとうございました！